# ASP.NET Webforms routing with extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, file-extension

I have a simple ASP.NET Webapplication project with url-routing and want to "allow" routes with the fileextension like ".html", e.g...

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/cms/test.html
http://www.mywebsite.com/cms/sub/test.html
http://www.mywebsite.com/cms/sub/sub/test.html
```

My global.asax routes looks like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "cms/{a1}", "~/default.aspx");
```

The route is matched with when i access the website like this:
http://www.mywebsite.com/cms/test

If i try this one, it doens't work too:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "cms/{a1}.html", "~/default.aspx");
```

EDIT: Always i get an 404 error. I think that .net looks for the physical file...

Any ideas?

Comment: You should verify if IIS isn't routing these request before .NET working process.

Comment: How can i do this? In the Mime-Types properties?

Comment: The easiest troubleshoot is to place a HTML file on the path you're routing to and test if its called. If you keep getting 404, then there's nothing to do with IIS and the problem is with your route. Otherwise, it's IIS getting in your way.

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed it on my on with the following property "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" inside the  like this:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
    </handlers> 
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  This was driving me crazy for a long time.