# routes.MapPageRoute does not work with point?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes

I am using asp.net webform. In my application, I show user page like http://localhost/username

In RouteConfig.cs I register routes like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("default", "", "~/default.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("user", "{id}", "~/user.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("search", "search/{id}", "~/search.aspx");
```

but when a username contains point (.) it shows 404 error.

http://locahost/name.lastname this shows error.

Any hint? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought it was related with extensions. So, I found an answer about this.
[ASP.NET Webforms routing with extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343195/asp-net-webforms-routing-with-extension)

I add this to web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
</handlers>
```

and it is worked!