# Register .json route in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, routes, global-asax

Is there any way to register `.json` format in Global.asax?

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.DynamicData" %>
<script runat="server">
     Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
         RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
     End Sub

     Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)

         routes.MapPageRoute("", "Data.json", "~/Data.aspx")

     End Sub
</script>
```

I tried to use above code, but I doesn't work.

Comment: Are you want to download JSON file? It's not clear what you're trying to do, but I didn't recommend using JSON file extension for ASPX page route.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I want to set a '.json' format in routing in order to when the user types mysite.com/data.json it reads the data from data.aspx

Comment: What error do you get? A 404?

Comment: If you are getting a 404 - this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514230/routes-mappageroute-does-not-work-with-point